# Is there a comprehensive reference list of all Serpent commands?

Tags: solidity, serpent

Solidity has a particularly nice, comprehensive [set of docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), and a flashy [GitHub homepage](https://ethereum.github.io/solidity/).

Is there an equivalent set of documentation for Serpent?

Comment: Not that I've found. The wiki and actual Serpent source code are the best resources I've found.

Comment: It might be better to ask for all serpent commands rather than asking if there is a list out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two resources that may or may not be outdated, but provide a good overview of Serpent commands available. Note: It is not necessarily comprehensive.

https://ethereumbuilders.gitbooks.io/guide/content/en/serpent_tutorials.html

https://mc2-umd.github.io/ethereumlab/docs/serpent_tutorial.pdf

Comment: What about building up a reference list here rather than linking external content? :-)